# Calculating sum of row into a column

Tags: sql-server, casting, sum

I'm a bit confused on why does my number not add to each other but they seem to just stack together. I did some research and tried to cast my data into numbers but doesn't seem to give me the outcome I want. Any ideas?
Picture Provided are the examples of my results when executed. The Other is the data in Table.
[MS SQL 2019]

[Result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EMTQ.png)
[Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUdcA.png)

--This is what I came up with so far (Note: I have more columns to add in 100+)--

```
select PartNumber, sum(cast(a01b + a02a as int)) 
as total
from bincount
group by PartNumber
```

Comment: 1) MySQL 2019 not exists. Maybe you use MS SQL 2019 (SQL Server 2019)? 2) Remove pictues but provide code-formatted CREATE TABLE + INSEDRT INTO and table-formatted desired output.

Comment: @Akina Yes, it is MS sql 2019. I'll add the pictures. I also get this error message when running the query with 100+ rows         [Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator.]

Comment: @Akina The table was imported from an excel sheet into SQL.

Comment: @Akina I'm unable to upload the picture, but I just want to calculate the values in each row and use the Total column to show all those columns that have value added together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the data type of both columns, and whether they are nullable, because `NULL + 17` will give you NULL, not 17.

Sum many rows with NULLs in them, and the sum will be way less than what you'd expect.

You might be forced to write using [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT SUM(
         COALESCE(a20a, 0) + COALESCE(a20b, 0)
       ) AS total
```

or, but this should not be necessary,

```
         COALESCE(CAST(a20a AS INT), 0) + COALESCE(CAST(a20b AS INT), 0)
```

Or you can add after the `SUM`, which is faster:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(a20a),0) + COALESCE(SUM(a20b),0)
```

Now the NULL values will be ignored (NULL + 5 + 10 is NULL, but SUM(5, NULL, 10) is 15), unless a *whole column* is entirely made of NULLs (in this case, SUM returns NULL and not 0); the COALESCE tackles this edge case. If you are sure you have at least one non-NULL in each column, you can do without the COALESCE.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a shot and get back to you

Comment: This does work. How do I remove this NULL Value for future references?

Comment: How would you go about putting this as an update statement when data is entered in one of the columns?

Comment: @Jvang sorry, but I don't understand. You want to remove the NULL values? You can run `UPDATE table SET a20a = 0 WHERE a20a IS NULL`. And you can set the column with a DEFAULT value of 0 and set it as non-nullable. You have to do this with a DDL for *all* the columns though.

Comment: Ah ok. How would I go about this to auto populate in a existing column? and then extract that data into another table?

Comment: @Jvang autopopulate... you can't. But you can set each row's rowTotal to the total of two (or as many as you like) rows: `UPDATE table SET rowTotal = COALESCE(a20a,0) + COALESCE(a20b,0), anotherTotal = COALESCE(a44a,0) + COALESCE(a44b,0);`. I don't understand what you mean with "extract that data into another table"; but you can add another question with your attempts and an example of the output you expect. If you add to the new question a comment with "@LSerni" in it, I'll be pinged and will give it a try.

Comment: My Apologies @LSerni, I  will make another Question on this. What I meant by extracting is pulling data from one table into another table with same PK and rows.

Comment: @Jvang Oh, in that case you can create the new table from a SELECT (CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT ...). If you want to "clone" the table, then CREATE TABLE table2 LIKE oldtable; INSERT INTO table2 SELECT ... FROM oldtable.
If you specify a field as ... COALESCE(a20a,0) AS a20a, then the new table will have zeroes instead of NULLs. *Remember that the field will still be regarded as nullable, so new values inserted might be NULL*.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql query - calculate file id count

```
select file_id , 
       count(ID) 
from table 
group by file_id 
ORDER BY ID DESC limit 30;
```

Comment: I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: It shows my total as 1 for 198 rows; however, I only have values in 17 rows. I don't think this would work in my case. Thank you.